# VBA: Edit ColorIndex in a protected sheet without providing passwrod

Tags: vba, excel

Today I am here with a tricky question, not sure how or whether this is possible.

My code having a line to edit the color of a button.

```
Dim myshape As Shape: Set myshape = Thisworkbook.Worksheet("Mastersheet").Shapes("Button 4")
With myshape
        .TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 15
End With
```

Now my issue is that the Sheet called 'Mastersheet' is a protected sheet which cant be left unprotected. And my macro should be able to change the color of that button without un protecting the sheet.

I tried to left the fields unprotected where this button is placed, using with "Allow user to edit this range" option available, but thats not working. Is there any solution to overcome this??

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it edit object rather than range?

Comment: When you protect the sheet try allowing the edit of objects.  But why can't you unprotect in the vba right before the edit then immediately protect it again?  It would be way to fast for anyone to do anything.

Comment: @QHarr, this is to edit the button (So it will be Object right)

Comment: @  Scott Craner, thanks. i will think about it... But I like to know if there is another way... So that I don't want to feed the password on my Macro

Comment: that would have been my first thought though i am with Scott about considering unprotecting to make your changes.

Comment: okay, I tried, but please tell me how to feed password into the vba code by default. When i add the code to my master code, it ask for password (evertime I run it) to un protect the sheet

Comment: `Worksheets("Mastesheet").Unprotect password`  Then change the `unprotect` to `protect`.  You can also pasword protect your code in the vbe, this will stop most non serious lookers.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Craner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click your Sheet > Select PROTECT SHEET > Provide your desired Password > Scroll down > Checkin EDIT OBJECTS

Which will help your macro to update the Objects... (But there is one risk the users who are using, also able to update the text fields of any objects you placed in that sheet)

Good luck and choose wisely which options suits your need.